# How to copy data from old array to new array using while or for loop

Tags: java

I have this code but it prints null word 20 times. 
Please help me understand why the elements are not copied instead.

```
public class StrList {
    public void add(String y) {
        if (currsize == elements.length) {
            System.out.println("no more room to add " + y);  // fix this to increase space instead!
        }
        int newSize = elements.length * 2;
        newElements = new String [newSize];
        for (int i = 0; i <currsize; i++){        
            elements = newElements; }

        elements[currsize] = y;
        currsize += 1;      // or currsize++
    }
```

Comment: `elements = newElements;` should be `newElements[i] = elements[i];` I guess. You don't even use the `i` in your loop body. Also - paranthesis are recommended for a loop body.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I corrected that in my code and now the code doesn't print anything.

Comment: First, when you're printing you're calling `get()` method which its code isn't provided here. Second, I encourage you to use a debugger and to go step by step throughout your code until you understand the problem. Using a debugger is a very basic skill and super important for any developer.

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I see a reassignment to elements done currSize times. Maybe you forgot a [i]?